# Peculiar happenings in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have just started an internship in I've had to learn a lot on my own.  I'm learning MS SQL Server, but having a strange problem.  I have a DB that has four small tables.  Each one has a script to drop the table, recreate the table (I've avoided FK dependencies for the time being), and execute a demo query.

Problem 1:  When I first started SQL Server Managmenent Studio would execute the script, but one table didn't show up in the Object Explorer.  If I tried to execute a demo query from the same .sql file, it executed with no problem.  If I tried to access it from another .sql, the table didn't exist.  After many times of successfully executing the script, it finally just showed up.

Problem 2: Similar problem.  When I updated one table, the changes wouldn't be reflected in queries.

Problem 3: Queries will fail, but if I click execute again with no changes being made, it will usually work correctly.

Problem 4: When I use an alias for a field name, sometimes the alias is recognized and sometimes it isn't.  I've literally had single query in which the alias would work in one place, but not work in another and I had to use a fully qualified name.

I've tried the refresh and refresh local cache, but those seem to have no effect.  If I exit Management Studio, that seems to usually fix the first two  problems.

Am I going nuts or am I just in the dark about some weird specifics of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you make a schema change you need to right-click on the "Tables" node for the database in management studio and hit refresh.

If you change a column or something in a table, right-click the table and refresh.

The refresh local cache only updates the intellisense stuff, and the refresh only updates the GUI.  If you modify a table with SQL and do not refresh it in the UI, the query can still use the updated table.

If you query fails, you either have a bad query or it's not pointed at the database or connection you think it is.

For aliases, there are places where they will not work (update statements, for example) but if you don't post queries where they don't work we cannot read your mind and tell you what's wrong.

If you have specific queries that are failing, post them.

Comment: As far as the refreshes go, I don't think I was clicking on the tables.  I just thought a refersh anywhere in the Object Explorer would refresh everything.

Comment: Generally, if you click a parent (or parent's parent) in the tree it will refresh everything beneath it.  Also, for queries, you can right click and do `change connection` (I think that's the label) to see the actual connection.  Which connection a query was tied to was confusing to me at first.